# Sending away the mother bird, mitzvah at the onset?

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, ki-teitzei, birds, shiluach-haken

The *Mishnah* in Chullin 141a says

> הנוטל אם על הבנים ר' יהודה אומר לוקה ואינו משלח וחכמים אומרים לוקה משלח ואינו לוקה
>
> Someone who takes the mother bird with the children, R' Yehudah says they're lashed and don't need to send away the mother bird. The Sages say send the bird away and they're not lashed.

The discussion there makes it clear the dispute is what's the status of this *mitzvah*: לאו שקדמו עשה, a negative *mitzvah* which was preceded by a positive *mitzvah* (so there's lashes, as per Makkos 14b), or a לאו הניתק לעשה, a negative *mitzvah* which was given over for positive rectification (so there's no lashes, see Makkos 14b-16b).

Now, I'm basing my understanding of these two types of *mitzvos* on how **Rashi** in Makkos *loc cit.* explains it (I am aware there are other explanations, I'm just not familiar with them). If I understand him correctly, לאו שקדמו עשה is that the positive *mitzvah* is possible before the negative *mitzvah* (ex: a rapist has to marry his victim, and can never divorce her). Whereas לאו הניתק לעשה is the positive *mitzvah* **is only possible** after breaking the negative *mitzvah* (returning stolen property for example). Therefore, the explanation of the dispute in sending away the mother bird based on the that *gemarra* in Chullin is that R' Yehudah understands "שלח תשלח" is מעיקרא משמע, at the onset, so it's possible before the negative *mitzvah*. The Sages seem to hold the *mitzvah* to send her away is only possible to fulfill **after transgressing** the negative *mitzvah*.

Therefore it would seem to me that **there's no *mitzvah* at the onset to send away the mother bird** according to the Sages, unless the person transgressed the *mitzvah* of taking them all. Only R' Yehudah says there's a *mitzvah* to first send her away. Now, I would guess practically it makes no difference, if you want the eggs and don't want to even momentarily break the Torah, send away the mother. But it seems there's no *mitzvah* *lechatchila* (at the onset) according to the Sages.

However, it sounds like from various sources that there is a *mitzvah lechatchila*. I found in **Rambam**'s Sefer HaMitzvos *Shoresh* 6 that he writes explicitly that sending away the mother bird is a לאו הניתק לעשה, yet it is a positive *mitzvah* since *Chazal* call it a *mitzvah* (I'm guessing an example is Kiddushin 39b). He seems to learn לאו הניתק לעשה differently than **Rashi**. Does he mean it's a *mitzvah lechatchila*, at the onset? He lists the *mitzvah* in *Mitzvas Aseh* 148 as to send away the mother bird; no prerequisites. How does **Rashi** understand things? Would he say the gemarra in Kiddushin that says it's a *mitzvah* is like R' Yehudah? Or am I misunderstanding the principles at work.

I'd like an explanation which summarizes the various opinions. What's motivating this question is many people seem to think there's a *mitzvah* to go out and send away mother birds, but according to the Sages (who are the final *halacha*), there's no such thing. It simply rectifies the transgression.

Edit: it should be noted I saw the **Tiferes Yisroel** addresses this issue and writes (Makkos 3:4 in [*Yachin*](https://www.sefaria.org/Yachin_on_Mishnah_Makkot.3.30.1))

> וחכמים אומרים משלח ואינו לוקה
> דס"ל שלח **גם** אחר לקיחה משמע, והו"ל ניתק לעשה:
>
> The Sages say send away the mother bird and you won't get lashes, since they hold the verse implies **also** to send her away after you take, therefore it's nitak le'aseh.

He seems to hold the Sages agree to Rabbi Yehudah it's a לאו שקדמו עשה, but the way I explained things I feel like that makes it mutually exclusive to being a לאו הניתק לעשה, so I don't understand.

Comment: The chinuch mentions that since if the mother dies, flies away on her own, or someone else takes it and sends it away, you won't be able to be mekayim the mitzvah, it's best to send it away first and not take the mother and then send it away in order to have the lav first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various sources which sound like there **is no *mitzvah* at the onset**; only once transgressing the negative *mitzvah*.

**Teshuvos HaRashba** I § 18 says there's no *beracha* on sending away the mother bird, as it's a *mitzvah haba'ah baveira*, a *mitzvah* that only occurs through a transgression. The [**Ritva**](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.16a.10?lang=bi&p2=Ritva_on_Makkot.16a.3&lang2=bi) to Makkos 16a sounds like there's no *mitzvah* except after transgressing. The **Rambam** at the beginning of Hilchos Shechitah, when he specifies the *mitzvos* included in the section, writes `לשלח האם, אם לקחה על הבנים`, which is pretty clear that the *mitzvah* is only once transgressing.

This is also how the [**Kesef Mishnah**](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Ritual_Slaughter.13.19?lang=bi&p2=Kessef_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Ritual_Slaughter.13.19.2&lang2=bi) understands (and thus asks a question on the **Rambam**, see there). The **Sha'agas Aryeh** § 33 and [**Rav Yerucham Fishel Perlow**](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%90) (Sefer HaMitzvos LeRasag II [*Lo Sa'aseh* § 137](https://www.sefaria.org/Commentary_on_Sefer_Hamitzvot_of_Rasag%2C_Negative_Commandments.137?lang=en)) concur.

However, I found some *Achronim* who learn like the **Tiferes Yisroel**, that there is **also** a *mitzvah* at the onset. Namely, The **Rashash** to Chullin 141b, and **Penei Yehoshua** to Makkos 14b.

The **Penei Yehoshua** asks a question similar to the one posted here. He says that according to **Rashi**, who holds when it's a לאו הניתק לעשה the positive *mitzvah* is only possible after transgressing, how can sending away the mother bird be a לאו הניתק לעשה? The *mitzvah* is also possible before transgressing (ie: send her away)!

The **Rashash** also asks a question on **Rashi**. The [*gemarra*](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.141b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) asks how far must a person send away the mother bird? **Rashi** [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.141b.9?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Chullin.141b.9.1&lang2=bi) the *gemarra* to be asking in the case when a person transgressed and took them. The **Rashash** asks on **Rashi** why not make the case even when a person didn't transgress, and they simply want to fulfill the *mitzvah* to send it away?  You see both the **Rashash** and **Penei Yehoshua** understand there's a mitzvah at the onset.

In **Teshuvos Maharam Shik** [*Yoreh Deah* § 289](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1495&pgnum=200) he answers the **Rashash**'s question on **Rashi** that **Rashi** holds **there is no *mitzvah* at the onset**. This would also answer the **Penei Yehoshua**'s question on **Rashi**. Thus, the whole question posted here doesn't get started. **Rashi**, who holds it's impossible to fulfill the *mitzvah* of a לאו הניתק לעשה until transgressing, is consistent and holds the same by sending away the mother bird. Anyone who says there's a *mitzvah* at the onset, must understand לאו הניתק לעשה differently than **Rashi**.

Answer (score 0):

The [Aruch Hashulchan 292:6 -10](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.292?lang=bi)

He explains that according to the Rambam (and presumably Rashi as well) who hold its a Lav Hanitek L'asei, it has the status of a mitzvah asei that just so happens to have a lav attached to it. He says from the Terumas Hadeshen that there are many such mitzvohs. So in essence, there's a lchatchila mitzvah that includes doing the lav to get to it. The mitzvah is to grab the mother, thereby violating the lav, and then sending her away immediately to be mekyem the asei. He even says to make a bracha since that's the way to do the mitzvah, by first doing the lav.

Here is part of the text

> ונראה פשוט שחייב לברך בשעת שילוחה אקב"ו על שילוח הקן וכן מצאתי בס' תמים דעים להראב"ד הביא שם בס"ס קע"ט דברי בעל העיטור בשם הלכות פסוקות וז"ל והלכתא צריך לברך בשילוח הקן ובמעקה וכו' עכ"ל ואל תטעה בלשון תשו' הרשב"א (סי' י"ח) שכתב וכן כל מצוה שהיא באה מתוך עבירה כגון השבת הגזילה וכו' וליקח את האם כדי שנחזר ונשלח אותה וכו' אין מברכין ע"ש דה"פ דוודאי אם אוחזה כדי לשלחה מברך אך אם נוטלה עתה כדי לשלחה לאחר זמן דגם בזה קיים העשה כמו שנתבאר מ"מ בעת מעשה עשה עבירה ולכן לא יברך אח"כ כשישלחנה והוי כהשבת הגזילה **ולפ"ז אדרבא ראיה מהרשב"א דאם עשה המצוה כתקונה יברך עליה וגם בספר ת"ד שם מקודם הביא מי שרצה לומר שלא יברך מפני שיש בה גם לאו דלא תקח וגו' ודחי לה דכמה מ"ע שיש בהן גם לאו ומברכין עליהם ע"ש וכן עיקר לדינא** (וראיתי בבאה"ט שכתב שיש מחלוקת ע"כ יברך בלא שם ומלכות ע"ש וכן בפ"ת הביא בשם ת"נ שלא יברך שמא ימצא ביצים מוזרים ע"ש ואין כדאי לשומעם דא"כ לא נברך על תפילין שמא נפסל אות אחד וא"תדמעמידין על חזקה א"כ גם כאן כן וניכר שלא ראו הת"ד וגם תשו' הרשב"א והעיקר לדינא לברך אך ברכת שהחיינו נ"ל דלא לברך שהיא מצוה שאין בה שמחה ואינה מזמן לזמן ודו"ק).

The minhag today is to use a stick to chase the mother away which is not according to this Aruch Hashulchan.

Comment: Also refer to Minchas Chinuch - https://www.sefaria.org/Minchat_Chinukh.545.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: "there are many such mitzvohs" I can't think of any

Comment: @Robev I was wondering the same thing. Nazir might be one since he brings a korban chatas. Or any case of asei docheh lav, like tzitzis. Although, if he means to say that in such a case the lav is waived then there's plenty of cases. Shabbos in the Mikdash,