# לאו הניתק לעשה Is this still a laa'v for which one needs atonement

Tags: kaparah-atonement, negative-commandments

[Mishnah Makos 3(4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Makkot.3.4?lang=bi&with=Bartenura&lang2=en) says:

> This is the principle: With regard to any prohibition that entails a
> command to arise and perform a mitzva, he is not liable to receive
> lashes for its violation.

An example is:

> “You shall not take the mother with her fledglings; you shall send the
> mother, and the fledglings you may take for yourself”

[Deuteronomy 22:6–7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Makkot.3.4?lang=bi&p2=Deuteronomy.22.6&lang2=bi&aliyot2=0&w2=all&lang3=en). If he took the mother with her fledglings, he can avoid lashes by sending the mother away and only then taking the fledglings.

In the confession of Yom Kippur we ask for forgiveness

> עַל מִצְוַת עֲשֵׂה וְעַל מִצְוַת לֹא תַעֲשֶׂה. בֵּין שֶׁיֶּשׁ בָּהּ
> קוּם עֲשֵׂה. וּבֵין שֶׁאֵין בָּהּ קוּם עֲשֵׂה.
>
> For a positive commandment and for a negative commandment whether or
> not there is a “ command to arise and perform a mitzva”.

So it seems that even if he does the remedial act of sending the mother away, he still needs forgiveness for taking the mother with her fledglings in the first place.

Is that right?

related: [Sending away the mother bird, mitzvah at the onset?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85169/sending-away-the-mother-bird-mitzvah-at-the-onset)

Comment: It's common sense. Otherwise you could borrow anyone's things without permission.

Comment: Yeah. It just means that there are no lashes; the Torah prescribed a different remedy. It's still wrong to do it in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Atonement is still needed. See [ברטנורא על משנה יומא ח׳:ח׳:ג](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Yoma.8.8.3?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

> הניתק לעשה, תשובה מכפרת
>
> Regarding a prohibition that is repaired to a positive act, *teshuva* atones.